# Camera2 API with external USB camera

Tags: android, webrtc, android-camera2, kurento, uvc

I'am working in project to build a WebRTC communication between a Android device and the Web Page, so i used this github [WebRTC_Android](https://github.com/nhancv/nc-kurento-android)repository to implement the android side, and all work fine with the android device camera, but now i want use a external camera.

After analysing the code i found that it use  the   [Camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary) to read the camera stream, and i found [here](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/external-usb-cameras) that this API support external caméra, but for me the API doesn't even detect the caméra.

I'am asking if the API work with all type of external caméra ?, what type of caméra the API support ?, can i use the [UVC Camera Library](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera) with WebRTC istead of Camera2 API ?

Thanks

Comment: if your Android 9+ device doesn't support external camera natively you can either make a custom image that adds this support (https://source.android.com/devices/camera/external-usb-cameras) or integrate UVC library into a native app. There was a feature request made to integrate UVCCamera into react-native-webrtc library, which powers for example Jitsi Meet client on Android. https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/4937 You can support it

Answer (score 3):

Are you working with an Android Pie phone? The camera API to support external USB camera only works for an Android Pie phone with the right porting to support it. As I know, not all Android Pie phone got [this](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/external-usb-cameras) ported.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which phones support this?